# Exception as an Inner Class?

Tags: java, class, exception

```
public class Employee {
    private String name; // the employee's name 
    private String jobTitle; // the employee's job title
    private double wage; // the hourly wage for the employee
    // the amount of money the company currently owes the employee 
    protected double payOwed;

// Default starting wage
public static final double MINIMUM_WAGE = 10.0;

// Class variable: the highest wage any employee receives
private static double maxWage = 0;

/**********************************************************************
 * Constructor: Creates an employee given a name, job title, and wage.
 *
 * Parameters:
 *   theName: the name for the employee
 *   title: the job title for the employee
 *   wage: the employee's wage
 *
 * Errors: If wage is negative, writes error message and uses zero instead.
 **********************************************************************/
public Employee(String name, String title, double wage) {
    // Possible improvement: disallow null or empty names & titles
    this.name = name;
    jobTitle = title;
    // start out with no pay accumulated
    payOwed = 0;
    if (wage < 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: negative wages not allowed!");
        wage = 0;
    } // end if
    this.wage = wage;
    if (wage > maxWage)
        maxWage = wage;
} // end constructor


/**********************************************************************
 * Returns the employee's name.
 *********************************************************************/
public String getName() {
    return name;
} // end getName

/**********************************************************************
 * Returns the employee's job title.
 *********************************************************************/
public String getTitle() {
    return jobTitle;
} // end getTitle

/**********************************************************************
 * Returns the employee's wage
 *********************************************************************/
public double getWage() {
    return wage;
} // end getWage


/**********************************************************************
 * Changes the employee's job title
 * Parameter: new job title
 *********************************************************************/
public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
    jobTitle = newTitle;
} // end setTitle


/**********************************************************************
 * Gives the employee a raise.
 *
 * Parameter: the amount by which to raise this employee's hourly wage.
 *********************************************************************/
public void raise(double amount) throws EmployeeException{
    if (amount < 0){
        throw new EmployeeException();
    }
    else{
        wage += amount;
    }
    if (wage > maxWage)
        maxWage = wage;
} // end raise


/**********************************************************************
 * Pays the employee for a number of hours worked.  This increases the 
 * amount of pay owed to the employee.
 *
 * Parameter: the number of hours worked
 *********************************************************************/
public void pay(double hours) {
    payOwed += hours * wage;
} // end pay


/**********************************************************************
 * Returns the amount of pay owed to this employee.
 *********************************************************************/
public double amountToPay() {
    return payOwed;
} // end amountToPay


/**********************************************************************
 * Zeros the amount of pay owed to this employee.  Call this after you
 * write the employee a cheque for a pay period.
 *********************************************************************/
public void zero() {
    payOwed = 0;
} // end zero


/**********************************************************************
 * Creates a String representation of the Employee, including name,
 * job title, wage and pay owed.
 *
 * Return value: the string representation
 *********************************************************************/
public String toString() {
    return name + ": " + jobTitle + ", wage=$" + wage 
        + ", pay owed = $" + payOwed;
} // end toString


/**********************************************************************
 * Constructor: Creates an employee with the default starting wage, 
 * given a name and job title
 *
 * Parameters:
 *   name: the name for the employee
 *   title: the job title for the employee
 *   wage: the employee's wage
 *
 * Errors: If wage is negative, writes error message and uses zero instead.
**********************************************************************/
public Employee(String theName, String title) {
    this(theName, title, MINIMUM_WAGE);
} // end constructor


/**********************************************************************
 * Returns the highest wage any employee currently receives
 *********************************************************************/
public static double getMaxWage() {
    return maxWage;
} // end getMaxWage  

/**********************************************************************
 * Compares this employee with another object for equality.
 * We define equality to mean that the other object must be some kind
 * of employee and have the same name, job title and wage.
 * Parameter: another object to compare with this employee
 *********************************************************************/  
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof Employee) {
        Employee otherEmp = (Employee) other;
        return (otherEmp.name.equals(name) && 
          otherEmp.jobTitle.equals(jobTitle) && 
          otherEmp.wage == wage);
    }
    else {
      return false;
    } // end if
} // end equals

public class EmployeeException extends Exception{
    public EmployeeException(){
        super();
    }
}


 } // end class Employee
```

---

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee Alex = new Employee("Alex", "Mr", 20);
        try{
            Alex.raise(-5);
        }
        catch(EmployeeException e){
            System.out.println("You cannot do that");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I keep getting a message saying that Java cannot find the employee exception class. I was wondering why that is the case. does it have anything to do with the employee exception being an inner class? thanks.

Comment: `catch(Employee.EmployeeException e) {` ... or add in import for `Employee.EmployeeException`

Answer (score 0):

`EmployeeException` is defined within `Employee`.
You can access it as `Employee.EmployeeException`:

```
    try{
        Alex.raise(-5);
    }
    catch(Employee.EmployeeException e){
        System.out.println("You cannot do that");
    }
```